# Bootstrap grid column gutter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: My issue]

Hi everyone,
I want to make bootstrap grid like screenshot. But I am struggling with gutter between columns.

Border col-md-4 of the first row should be straight line vertically compare to border of col-md-4 of the second row.

How to make col-md-8 should take the gutter of col-md-4 on the right?

Is there any solution about this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z78aa325/)

Attention that this is only possible with [bootstrap libraries](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) (js + css)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can add right border to the first two `.col-md-4` blocks:

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/vXzxdV

```css
/* Heart of the matter */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .gutter .col-md-4 {
    border-right: 12px white solid;
  }
  .gutter .col-md-4:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.gutter .col-md-4 {
  background: #9c6;
}
.gutter .col-md-4:last-child {
  background: #69c;
}
.gutter .col-md-8 {
  background: #c69;
}
.gutter .row > div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 4px 0 0 8px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .gutter .row {
    margin: 8px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container gutter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4:last-child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4:last-child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```